# Изменить адрес и перейти

Tags: javascript, html, php

Здравствуйте. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать на сайте ссылку, чтобы к текущему адресу вида **site.ru/index.php?cat=8** (номер категории меняется, а фильтр нет) добавлялась строка **&filter_id=4** и страница обновлялась уже в новом виде **site.ru/index.php?cat=8&filter_id=4**. Нужен вид < a href="**current_page**&filter_id=4">

Answer (score 1):

Если на JavaScript, то выполнить переход можно изменив значение `location.href`:

```
location.href = location.href.replace(/([&|\?]?filter=\d+)|$/, ((location.href.match(/[&|?]filter=/) || ['?filter='])[0]) + '999999');
```

**999999** в данном случае ID фильтра

Comment: Большое спасибо, это то что нужно. Правда перед каждой загрузкой ссылка обрастает как снежный ком) Возможно это как-то решить? Не критично конечно, для меня и такой вариант сойдёт и фильтрация работает.

Comment: Исправил ответ, теперь параметр не дублируется

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="site.ru/?cat=<?php echo $_GET['cat'];?>&filter_id=4">
```

Речь об этом?

Answer (score 0):

Дополню ответ выше:

```
var number = 4;
location.href = location.href.indexOf('filter=') > -1 ? location.href.replace(/filter=[0-9]+/.exec(location.href), 'filter=' + number) : ((location.href.indexOf('?')>-1 ? '&' : '?') + 'filter=' + number);
```